# DVD's stop working after about an hour

Tags: vlc, dvd

I am running 14.04, and this past week on two occasions (with two different DVDs) I have been playing a DVD and it works great until it reaches a point where it just stops functioning. The video stops and the DVD drive starts making a lot of noise and the program freezes up. I've tried in both VLC and Parole Media Player. If I restart the program it still freezes at the same spot. Both DVDs were rented have no apparent scratches. I have a dual boot and in Windows it plays past the freeze point fine.

Has anybody experiences anything like this? It seems very strange.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. I guess you have faced a hardware problem, as I also had. I managed to fix it by flashing new firmware (check http://liggydee.cdfreaks.com/page/en/How-to-Flash/ ). Hopefully you are not out of luck and find a firmware update.

My drive is Optiarc DVD RW AD-7203S.